# understand .prj and what CRS is used (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, prj

I am trying to devise what CRS is being used by a shapefile published by the Slovenian Ministry of the Environment and Spatial Planning [here](https://dokumenti-pis.mop.gov.si/javno/veljavni/O61I/index.html). Unfortunately, I cannot download the .prj file, but I can open it in the browser (?) here is what I can see:

> PROJCS["Gk-XY",GEOGCS["GCS_Bessel_1841",DATUM["D_Bessel_1841",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Gauss_Kruger"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-5000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",15.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

I copied the above text in notepad and created a .prj file. When I open the shapefile in QGis and look at the info of the layer this is what I get:

[image: CRS Information]

When I try to overlay the shapefile to a georeferenced orthophoto with correct CRS (*EPSG:3794 - Slovenia 1996 / Slovene National Grid - Projected*) I can see that there is a translation:
[image: translation]

Can you help me find out what CRS has been used to create the shapefile?

Comment: Have look at either the website of the data provider, or go through all CRS listed on epsg.io which cover Slovenia.

Comment: The CRS information might be correct, but has no datum shift information from bessel to WGS84. Therefore you get the shift.

Comment: @Erik In the website there is no information about that, and I am going through the CRS on epsg.io but without meaningful results. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

found it. That was EPSG:3912 - MGI 1901 / Slovene National Grid - Projected! After an endless manual search on epsg.io.